# Buffer for features selected in the mapcanvas and writing to csv file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have some features selected by using "Select Features by Freehand" tool in QGIS and try to find the buffer for those selected features alone and write the city and state names within in the buffer to a csv file. My code and image is attached for a clear understanding. it is writing an csv file in the given location but nothing is found inside the csv.

[image]

And my code is

```
import csv
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
columns=['name', 'state' ]
for feature in selection:
  mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(50, 2)
  iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
  for f in iterFeat:
    geom2 = f.geometry()
    valTest = QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf)
    lsNearCities = []
    if valTest:
        idx = selection.fieldNameIndex('name')
        idx1 = selection.fieldNameIndex('state')
        nearCity = f.attributes()[idx]
        state = f.attributes()[idx1]
        state_and_cities = str(state) + "," + nearCity
        lsNearCities.append(state_and_cities)
        print lsNearCities
```

Comment: where is "feature" initialized?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake before and edited now.

Answer (score 1):

the Line,

```
feature = layer.selectedFeatures()
```

returns a list of QgsFeature. You will need to loop over it to process individual selections, like below.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(50, 2)
    iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
    for f in iterFeat:
      geom2 = f.geometry()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If i have n features selected in the map? how should i edit the code accordingly. Sorry for the simple question am new to python and QGIS

Comment: @AhamedFarook - updated answer.

Comment: I tried the above code in the edited post. It is showing "List Object has no attribute FieldNameIndex.

Comment: @AhamedFarook - selection.fieldNameIndex('name') should be feature.fieldNameIndex('name')

Comment: I replaced as you suggested, but am getting output as       ['1.44403824649,1.44403824649']
         ['0.591242026714,0.591242026714']
         ['0.174240282156,0.174240282156']
         ['0.0893665232556,0.0893665232556']      instead of state and city names of the of the buffered features.